# Вывод на разъем наушников сигнала определенной формы

Tags: android, аудио

Интересует, возможно ли в Android программно вывести на разъем наушников сигнал определенной формы, определенного значения (+/-):

- Синус
- Верхняя (нижняя) часть полуволны
- Меандр (сигнал прямоугольной формы)

Comment: Мне тоже интересно. Сгенерить wav просто. А вот как насчет вывести на выход наушников...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android